# Request Format inside an URL not working on Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I got an issue after upgrading from Symfony 4 to Symfony 5. When I'm trying to call a route without the request format I got an error that no route was found.

Here my Code from the routing.yml

```
reportbook:
    path:     /report.{_format}/{user_id}
    methods:  [GET]
    requirements:
        _format:    html|json|pdf
    defaults:
        _controller:    Controller\ReportController::showAction
        _format:        html
        user_id:        ~
```

These are the urls I tried to open:

example.com/report/12345      --- not working error: route not found

example.com/report.html/12345 --- works

example.com/report.json/12345 --- works

example.com/report.pdf/12345  --- works

Now I want, like specified inside the routing.yml, that the default format is html.
Befor the Upgrade to Symfony 5 everything worked.

Comment: Not sure why it used to work but just for kicks try adding a format (not _format) to your route definition [as shown in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/routing.html#special-parameters).

Comment: I think this is about dot between report and format